# Update existing variables when in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, var

In JavaScript, when I add variables to an array and then update each element in the array, why does the variable have the same value when output in the console?

In the below I would expect all variables to show `777` in the console but they show 0.

When the array is logged `[777,777,777]` is shown as expected.

```js
var number1 = 0;
var number2 = 0;
var number3 = 0;

var numbers = [number1, number2, number3];

function updateNumbers() {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    numbers[i] = 777;

    console.log(numbers);

    console.log(number1);
    console.log(number2);
    console.log(number3);
  }

}

updateNumbers();
```

Comment: Because `number1` and `numbers[0]` are not the same variable.

Answer (score 2):

when you create your array you are passing the variables by value, not a reference to the variable.

```js
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var c = 3;
var test = [a, b, c];
console.log(test);
```

you can do what you want (sort of), but you need to use objects.

```js
var a = {
  value: 1
};
var b = {
  value: 2
};
var c = {
  value: 3
};

var test = [a, b, c];
// test[0] refers to a
// test[1] refers to b
// test[2] refers to c

function updateNumbers() {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    test[i].value = 777;
  }
}

updateNumbers();

console.log(test); // this wont output like in your example
console.log(a.value);
console.log(b.value);
console.log(c.value);
```